# Copy and rename new files with file names from an excel sheet?

Tags: linux, excel, batch-file, sed

I have to create about 40+ employee evaluation forms (I have the excel template for the forms) for my work and I have all their names in an excel sheet.

I was wondering/hoping if there was a way to automate the process of copying the template, then renaming it based on the employee's name in excel and putting the new file in a folder with the name of the employee.

I can use both linux or windows for this too. I feel like theres gotta be some SED expression to handle this for me.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you have a sheet with all the names, you can do file-SaveAs, and change the outputfile type to tab-delimted text, using a .txt extension. Then it should be simple to write a loop to do the file processing. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a new file, `employees.txt`, that has each employees name on a new line.  Hopefully this isn't a problem because there are ~40 employees.  I'm sure there's a macro out there that can automate the process.
2. In linux, just to be safe, execute `dos2unix employees.txt`
3. Copy the template, `template.xls`, to the `employees.txt` dir, `employeesDir`
4. Execute this script in linux:

   ```
   cd employeesDir;
   employees=`cat employees.txt`;
   for e in $employees; do 
      mkdir $e; 
      cp template.xls 
      $e/$e.xls; 
   done;
   ```

Comment: This solution assumes there are no spaces in the names. You can eliminate that problem with `while read e ; do .... ; done < employees.txt` (and convert all `$e` to `"$e"`. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be easiest using `awk`. You'll of course have to save as a text file

```
$ ls
copy.awk  names  name.skel
$ cat copy.awk 
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { skeleton = "name.skel" }

{ system("cp '" skeleton "' '" $1 "_" $2 ".eval'") }

$ cat name.skel 
skeleton
$ cat names
last first junk
rugbert user
$ awk -f copy.awk names
$ ls
copy.awk  last_first.eval  names  name.skel  rugbert_user.eval
$ cat last_first.eval 
skeleton
$ cat rugbert_user.eval 
skeleton
```

Or, reduced to a one-liner:

```
awk '{system("cp \'name.skel\' \'" $1 "_" $2 ".eval\'")}' names
```

This assumes you want them named `lastname_firstname.eval` and the columns are `lastname firstname ...`; obviously, change names and numbers as necessary.
If you use a csv, you'll need to add `-F,`.